# PHP - How to call another function in a class dynamically

Tags: php, function, class, oop

My PHP codes :

```
class FrontEndController extends BaseController {

    public function Welcome()
    {
        return View::make('frontend.index');
    }

    public function Modules($param="")
    {
        /* convert parameter "$param" be a function */      
        $prefix = "Mod_";  // func prefix's
        if (function_exists($this->$prefix.$param)) {
            return $this->$prefix.$param();
        }else
        {
            return $param;      
        }
    }

    protected function Mod_product(){
        return "You are called CATEGORY";
    }
    protected function Mod_promo(){
        return "You are called PROMO";
    }

}
```

When i use `FrontEndController->Modules('product');` i want it return value from **Mod_product()**, so also when I use `FrontEndController->Modules('promo');` it will return value from **Mod_promo()**. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [method_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php):

```
    $prefix = "Mod_";  // func prefix's

    $function = $prefix.$param;

    if ( method_exists( $this, $function ) ) {      
        return $this->$function();      
    } else {
        return $param;      
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few mistakes in your code:

function_exists does not work for classes, use `method_exists` instead.

```php
if (function_exists($this->$prefix.$param)) {
```

This does not work either, use `call_user_func` instead.

```php
return $this->$prefix.$param();
```

Corrected code:

```php
class FrontEndController extends BaseController {

    public function Welcome()
    {
        return View::make('frontend.index');
    }

    public function Modules($param="")
    {
        /* convert parameter "$param" be a function */      
        $prefix = "Mod_";  // func prefix's
        $fcn = $prefix.$param; // save name of function

        if (method_exists($this, $fcn)) {
            return call_user_func(array($this, $fcn));
        }else
        {
            return $param;      
        }
    }

    protected function Mod_product(){
        return "You are called CATEGORY";
    }
    protected function Mod_promo(){
        return "You are called PROMO";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your Modules function like this

```
$this->{$prefix . $params}();
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The [Reflection Class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) is the ideal tool for this. It's a Swiss army knife for classes.

```
public function Modules($param="")
{
    /* convert parameter "$param" be a function */      
    $prefix = "Mod_";  // func prefix's
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
    if($reflection->hasMethod($prefix.$param)) {
        return $this->$prefix.$param();
    }else
    {
        return $param;      
    }
}
```